# Using VCPKG with cmake and Qt 6 for Windows ARM64

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vcpkg

Qt 6.2 introduced Windows on Arm support (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85820). I tried to create a new cmake project set up using Qt Creator and everything works fine. Then I wanted to add some external packages to my project using vcpkg. The standard way to use vcpkg with cmake is using the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE variable (as mentioned [here](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/). However, when I clicked on project settings in Qt Creator (Projects > Build) it seems that Qt Creator has already set up the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE variable to another file

[image: Qt Creator CMake settings for Qt 6.3.0 MSCV 2019 ARM64]

Presumably, this is done so that it is possible to cross-compile an ARM64 binary from a x64 machine. However, this prevents me from setting up vcpkg within my Qt project. Is there a way to get around this issue? Does CMake support multiple toolchain files or is there an alternative setup for my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that VCPKG provides a way to achieve this as explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/integration.md#using-multiple-toolchain-files):

> To use an external toolchain file with a project using vcpkg, you can set the cmake variable VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE on the configure line:
>
> cmake ../my/project \
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake \    -DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../my/project/compiler-settings-toolchain.cmake

So in my case, I can just qt toolchain file using VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE option.